# How to eager load grandchildren of an aggregate with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, performance

I have the following class structure:

```
class TestCase {
  public IList<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}

class Step { 
  public IList<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

class Action { }
```

I want to load a `TestCase`, all `Step`s, and all `Event`s in one query and avoid the Select N+1 problem.

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090218060837/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/06/eager-loading-aggregate-with-many-child-collections.aspx) solves the problem of loading the `Step`s with `TestCase`s (using `IMultiQuery`), but how would I load the `Action`s too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful of your cross product here.  To handle more than one level deep for eager fetching, you'll need to use a <set> instead of a <bag> or <list>.  This will guarantee  that you don't have duplicate 'Steps' in your Test Case.  Finally, to get this to work use the following:

```
var result =  session.CreateCriteria(typeof (TestCase))
                .CreateAlias("Steps", "s")
                .CreateAlias("s.Actions", "a")
                .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaUtil.DistinctRootEntity);
                .List();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what that referenced post discussed. Just `Add` the 3rd criteria onto the 2nd criteria, instead of both of them on the 1st criteria.

```
var result = session.CreateMultiCriteria()
            .Add(criteria1
                .Add(criteria2)
            )
            .List();
```